# I am only able to print up to "red: 1" only, after which my program ends due to usage of break statement

Tags: java, arrays

Please see this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] names=new String[5];
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 colour:");
        for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++)
        {
            names[i]=scan.nextLine();
        }
        String[] numbers=new String[5];
        Scanner scan2=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers:");
        for(int j=0; j<numbers.length;j++)
        {
            numbers[j]=scan.nextLine();
        }
        OUTER:
        for (int k = 0; k < names.length; k++)
        {
            System.out.println(names[ k ] + ":");
            break OUTER;
        }
        INNER:
        for (int l = 0; l < numbers.length; l++)
        {
            System.out.println(numbers[ l ]);
            break INNER;
        }
    }
}
```

I am a newbie, learning Array as of now, in Java. I want to print the outcome of the code above as follows:

```
Enter 5 numbers:
//Say:
RED
GREEN
BLUE
PINK
YELLOW
Enter 5 numbers:
1
2
3
4
5

//Output of the code should be:
RED: 1
GREEN: 2
BLUE: 3
PINK: 4
YELLOW: 5
```

How can I print the array? I am only able to print up to "RED: 1" only, after which my program ends due to `break` statement.

Comment: Why are you using `OUTER` and `INNER` labels ? It would be much easier to do this without them.

Comment: Why are you using the `break` statement anyway if it stops you from doing what you need?

Comment: Please do not add "please help" messages to your questions, especially in the title. Readers are aware you want help, and messages explicitly to that effect may be read as begging, which is not always received well by volunteers. See also [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/472495) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255196/472495).

Answer (score 2):

Your last for does not a have any purpose. Just try :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] names=new String[5];
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 colour:");
        for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++){
            names[i]=scan.nextLine();
        }
        String[] numbers=new String[5];
        System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers:");
        for(int j=0; j<numbers.length;j++) {
            numbers[j]=scan.nextLine();
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < names.length; k++){
            System.out.println(names[ k ] + ":"+ numbers[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

ANd it's stop at the first because you break your for

Comment: I just ran it. Don't have any error. Where do you think there will be one ?

Comment: `numbers[j]=scan.nextLine()` will read the complete line of numbers while his logic is to make array out of that and when in next loop he tries to `numbers[2]` it will through error. because only numbers[0] will have element.

Comment: I know but in this case it looks like he write a int and then enter. If not he wouldnt have "RED :1" but "RED : 12345"

Comment: he edited the input output portion. you are right. But remove that `OUTER:` :p

Comment: I dont see the use of it neither. But it looks like he want it so ... But i'll remove it. Better without ;)

Answer (score 1):

`scan.nextLine()` reads the whole line of input that is it reads until you don't enter `\n` new line charachter, so use `nextInt()` instead of that. Also each `System.out.println()` is used to print a whole line so only one loop can be used. If `names` and `numbers` have same length. And change `numbers[]` from `String` to `int`, that would be more type safe.

```
 int numbers[] = new int[5];

 for(int j=0; j<numbers.length;j++)
    {
        numbers[j]=scan.nextInt();
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < names.length; k++)
    {
        System.out.println(names[ k ] + ":" + numbers[k]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of elements be it color or numericals that you're trying to get from the user is fixed here i.e 5, why complicate things? Use a single for loop to print all the contents of both the arrays:

```
for(int k=0;k<names.length;k++){
System.out.println(names[k] + ":"+numbers[k]);
}
```

Comment: yep... As far as I see @beenu is trying to accept an array of numbers using scan.nextLine(), instead declaring numbers as an array of integers and modifying the line to numbers[j] = scan.nextInt(); would be more data type safe.